# Обрезается часть даты из строки с меткой времени при вставке в ячейку excel

Tags: строки, datetime, powershell

Имеется строковый массив с метками времени в формате **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"**. Я пытаюсь привести эти метки к формату **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"**, вставить полученный массив в excel-столбец и конвертировать весь лист в txt-файл, разделенный символами табуляции. Теперь суть проблемы.
Если я вставляю метки в формате **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"** - в итоговом txt получаю корректную метку.

А при вставке преобразованных меток в формате **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"** в итоговый txt записывается обрезанная метка вида **"mm:ss.f"**. При этом если убрать пробел между датой и временем, и вставлять **"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.fff"** то в итоговый txt также попадает полная метка.
Подскажите, как исправить проблему?

Comment: *Подскажите, как исправить проблему?* Если всё это выполняется кодом PS (иначе зачем добавлен его тег?) - то просто избавиться от промежуточного Экселя и сливать в файл прямо из PS.

Comment: Если же не хочется отказываться от Экселя, можно в начале значения добавить одинарную кавычку, и записывать в поле значение `"'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"`.